# How do I change the default monitor in multiple monitor PC?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, tv

I got 2 monitors. Sharp and Samsung. The Samsung one is the bigger one and obviously I want to watch a movie maximized on that one.

Start menu is on my SHARP tv. If I go full screen with an app, it also gets maximized at the SHARP tv. What about if I want that to show up on my SAMSUNG TV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running Windows, right click on a blank area of your desktop, choose Screen Resolution and your settings are right there. Choose to extend the displays, drag the displays to the left or right, if they're different sizes, you can actually move them up or down to accommodate "aligning the bottom" or top, click the one you want to be the primary, and checkmark the "Make this my main display", since it is apparently not, based on the question.

If it's not Windows 7 or 8, sorry, I don't know off hand.